# Retina Macbook headphone jack built-in mic no device driver (bootcamp)

Tags: boot-camp, microphone, headphone-jack, macbook-pro-retina

I have a retina MBP. There is only one headphone jack, which allows for headphones with built in mics (like the apple iphone headphones) to be plugged in and used along with the microphone.

This works on OSX, I can switch to the mic in the headset and use it.

But in Windows, the mic does not show up in my recording devices list, therefore it cannot be used.

I've already tried to see whether my drivers are up to date, and have re installed the BootCamp drivers as well. The mic will just not show up as a device.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

The headphone device is: Cirrus Logic CS4206B (AB 40)

Thanks,

Comment: Related http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1222825

Comment: same problem here. any success with this ?